# Android Persistent Botom Sheet Height Related to Parent

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, paytm

In android, the Bottom Sheet we use for development requires a peek height to be specified which decides the height of the bottom sheet visible initially to the user. I want this to be related to another view in my Layout ( in this case I want the layout to be matched with the coordinator layout). Actually, I want the view to be like of MyAirtel / Paytm App which has the bottom sheet adjusted according to screen height and width.

Here is the coordinator layout code: -

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_github_emoji"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/home_screen_bottom_sheet_color"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="600dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.example.daggerfirst.fragments.HomeFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The coordinator layout is stretched in its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `app:behavior_peekHeight="600dp"` and it will use the default height for the provided content. If the content covers the entire screen, then the peek height will be 50% of the screen height

Comment: I want the bottom sheet to match the parent irrespective of the content inside it. Like if the bottom sheet don't have any content it will still cover the coordinator layout

Comment: change the first attribute android:layout_height="0dp" of CoordinatorLayout to match_parent